# How do I write alchohol formulas?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have a task to write a formula for 2,4 dimethyl-hexane-1-ol.
If I am incorrect, please suggest me how to write it, but I believe it should look like this:

CH3-CH2-CH2-CH2-CH-CH2-CH2-CH2
/
OH
So it has 8 C, 16 H and 1 O, but I am not sure if that is where the OH should go (4th CH in the drawing as in 2,4).
Also does "1-ol" mean there is only one OH?

In short, how do I count where does a OH goes?

Comment: No, that's not how pretty much all of it works. What do you think "hexane" means, to begin with?

Comment: 1-ol means the alcohol substituent is on the first carbon in the carbon chain. Similarly, 2-ol means -OH is on the second carbon.

Answer (score 1):

First up, no '1-ol' doesn't mean there is one OH, the 1 signifies the position of the OH group in your parent chain (here ,hexane) which in this case is the C1 carbon. How many OH groups are present is represented by adding di/tri... as a prefix to '-Ol'.
You need to learn how to identify and number a parent chain in organic compounds first in order to make the structures of orgo compounds using their IUPAC names .

Anyway, OH group will just attach to a terminal alkene of hexane and whichever terminal you choose, you need to number it 1. This will cover the hexan-1-ol part.

The carbon in your parent chain, adjacent to the carbon you just numbered , would be numbered 2 and so on and so forth until you have covered all the carbons of your parent chain.

Now just attach a methyl group on the carbon numbered 2 and another methyl to the carbon numbered 4 and that will cover your 2.4 dimethyl.

Comment: [How to ask and answer nomenclature questions?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3066/how-to-ask-and-answer-nomenclature-questions)

Comment: @andselisk thank you, i am new to this site, are there any more such posts about how to answer specific type of questions?

Comment: No prob, the general advice is to include a citation for the current IUPAC recommendations since they are *the* authoritative source for chemical nomenclature. There not so many Meta posts regarding Q&Aing on a particular topic. For example, there is [FAQ update: How to ask (or close) questions that involve potentially controlled or dangerous substances?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3003), and you can always search Meta if you want to inform yourself.